# The Golfer Adventure - Chapter 1 : The vase

Tags: code-golf

## The Golfer Adventure

This is the first challenge ! There will be more challenges later that will require data from the previous challenge :)

### Chapter 1 : The Vase

Let's imagine a minute.. You are a powerful God, your powers are limitless but require one thing : Souls.
Each soul is here represented by a byte, each byte you use does sacrifice a soul.
So the goal is obviously to save the biggest amount of people while sacrificing the least amount of souls.

Your first challenge is to save a little village, the devil is willing not to destroy the entire village if you resolve his challenge.

#### The Challenge :

You have a vertical vase which can contain exactly 10 things (Air included).
If you put a thing in that vase, gravity will make that thing fall to the bottom.
If the vase is already full (and it's always full if you consider it as "full of air"), the input will replace the element at the top of the vase.

Here is the set of allowed things :

- Air `0 /`
- A Rock `1 / -`
- A Leaf `2 / ~`
- A Bomb `3 / x`

If there is a rock or a leaf on top of "A Bomb", it will explode and destroy the thing on the top of it.

The input is the list of the things you'll put in the vase every turn.

**Example :** 11231 : You'll put 2 rocks, then a leaf, then a bomb and finally a last rock.

When the vase is static, you can begin to count with the following rule :

- Rock adds 1 unit to the accumulator
- Leaf multiplies the accumulator by 2
- Bomb decrement the accumulator by 1
- Air does nothing

(You need to start counting from the top of the vase)

Here is the simulation we get using "11231" as input :

```
|-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  |-|  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |
| |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  |-|  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |
| |  | |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  |-|  | |  | |  | |  | |
| |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  |-|  | |  | |  | |
| |  | |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  |-|  | |  | |
| |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  |-|  | |
| |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |x|  | |
| |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|  |~|  |~|
| |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|  |-|
| |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  | |  |-|  |-|
```

And the output will be 2 (calculated as `((0 x 2) + 1) + 1`)
No need to print all the states of the vase !

#### The base program (Python3)

You can execute it to understand how it works.

```
def printVase(vase):
  for i in vase:
    if i == 1:
      print("|-|")
    elif i == 2:
      print("|~|")
    elif i == 3:
      print("|x|")
    else:
      print("| |")

def updateVase(vase):
  changed = False
  for i in range(len(vase), -1, -1):
    if i < len(vase) - 1:
      if vase[i+1] == 3 and vase[i] in [1,2]:
        vase[i], vase[i+1] = 0, 0
        changed = True
      if not vase[i+1] and vase[i] in [1, 2, 3]:
        vase[i], vase[i+1] = vase[i+1], vase[i]
        changed = True
  return changed

userInput = input("Vase : ")
vase = [0 for i in range(0, 10)]
oldVase = vase
while updateVase(vase) or userInput != "":
  if userInput != "":
    vase[0] = int(userInput[0])
  userInput = userInput[1::]
  printVase(vase)
  input()

accumulator = 0
for i in vase:
  if i == 1:
    accumulator += 1
  if i == 2:
    accumulator *= 2
  if i == 3:
    accumulator -= 1
print(accumulator)
```

#### Golfed version (Python3, no Vase Display) : 360 bytes = 360 points

```
def u(v):
  c=0
  for i in range(len(v),-1,-1):
    if i<len(v)-1:
      if v[i+1]==3 and v[i]in[1,2]:v[i],v[i+1],c=0,0,1
      if not v[i+1]and v[i]in[1,2,3]:v[i],v[i+1],c=v[i+1],v[i],1
  return c
l,v=input(),[0 for i in range(0, 10)]
while u(v)or l!="":
  if l!="":v[0],l=int(l[0]),l[1::]
a=0
for i in v:
  if i==1:a+=1
  if i==2:a*=2
  if i==3:a-=1
print(a)
```

**If you want to test if your program works correctly, you can test this input : 12122111131**

**Correct answer is 43** :) (Thanks Emigna)

#### Now for the points :

- (x) points where : x is the amount of bytes needed to write your program.
  If you answer after the next challenge is posted, points for this challenge won't be added to your total amount of points.

The goal is to keep a minimum amount of points during the whole challenge :)
If you skip one of the part of the challenge, you'll have (wx + 1) points by default for the skipped part (where wx is the worst score for that challenge).

#### Data that will be required for the next challenge :

Output when input = 10100000200310310113030200221013111213110130332101

#### Current Champion : [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

Good luck everyone !

Comment: What's with the "can contain exactly 10 things"? Does "Air" count as a thing? Is input guaranteed to be such that the vase will only contain 10 things (I don't see it catered for in the reference implementation)? Also the input that produces the data for next challenge seems to have more than 10 things (even if air is like nothing and bombs blow up the next thing on top of the air there will be 14 things, I think).

Comment: An input `333` constructs a vase `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3]` in your golfed algorithm and hence a score of `-3`, but shouldn't it be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]` and then a score of `-1` according to your specification?

Comment: @JonathanAllan the vase can ONLY contains 10 elements, Air is also an element. At start the vase will be [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (so it is already full of air), when the vase is full, the input will replace the element at the top of the vase. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: @Laikoni I forgot to specify that bombs doesn't explode when a bomb is on top of another one, thanks !

Comment: Output for 10100000200310310113030200221013111213110130332101 seems to be 22, right?

Comment: Yup :) But it's a secret !

Comment: Adding a tricky test-case like **12122111131** might be a good idea.

Comment: Nice one, I edited the question to add your test-case, thanks :)

Comment: If the input is "3311", will the vase then be empty? Ie. [..1,1,3,3] -> [.. , ,1,3] -> [.. , , , ]

Comment: "If you answer after the next challenge is posted, points for this challenge won't be added to your total amount of points." What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 - <del>208</del> <del>191 185 180 172 164</del> 156 bytes

```
t=filter(bool,map(int,input()))
i=a=0
n=len(t)
while 0<n-1>i<11:
 if(t[i]>=3>t[i+1]):del t[i:i+2];i,n=0,n-2
 i+=1
for x in t[9::-1]:a+=a+x%2*(2-x-a)
print a
```

The breakdown is it removes air and the bombs if it is on the stack then counts.

EDIT : I swapped to Python 2 to save a byte, but now the input should be put in braces like '3312123'

EDIT2 : Im also kinda proud of the accumulator count

EDIT3 : Thanks for all your suggestions I would never have thought I could get it so low

Comment: Nice first answer! I was thinking with Python as well but short of time today. Think you would have beaten my approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the kind comment :) First time I'm doing a code golf and I've got to say it's quite fun.

Comment: Use `t[:10][::-1]` instead of `reverse()` to save 4 bytes and also maybe use Python 2 to save a bracket on the `print`? Comes to 5 more souls saved for me :)

Comment: No Python2 for me since I would have to cast input() to str for it to work, killing 5 more souls. Nice catch on the [::-1]

Comment: btw, I didn't see anything in the question that says the input can' be wrapped in quotes. Just says "The input is the list of the things". Works in Python 2 :)

Comment: Nah this is kinda cheating, it's like removing the print and saying "The answer is in a"... well actually now that I look on the other code golfs thats exactly what they do.. I don't know.

Comment: but the input can be any combination of 0,1,2,3. How would you deal with a 0 at the start if it is not a string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49071/discussion-between-paris-douady-and-elpedro).

Comment: The input is a "list of things" so you can expect a list to be provided by the user (like `[0,1,2,3,0,1,..]`) in which case I believe you could do `t=filter(None,input())` and save 12 bytes.

Comment: ...and as it stands you could save 4 with `filter(None,map(int,input()))`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>28</s> 36 bytes

05AB1E uses [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
Î0KDvT¹g‚£`sTØõ:žwõ:ì}ÁT£ÀRS"<>·"è.V
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w44wS0R2VMK5Z-KAmsKjYHNUw5jDtTrFvnfDtTrDrH3DgVTCo8OAUlMiPD7CtyLDqC5W&input=MTIxMjIxMTExMzE)

Comment: Impressive as always :D It'll be hard to beat that

Comment: `T£ÀRS` `->` Tears `->` I'm crying alright...

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>58</s> 56  bytes

```
1+`0|(?<=.{9}).\B|3[12]

+-1=`2
$'
+`13

*\(1`3
-
)T`d
.
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MStgMHwoPzw9Lns5fSkuXEJ8M1sxMl0KCistMT1gMgokJworYDEzCgoqXCgxYDMKLQopVGBkCi4&input=MTIxMjIxMTExMzE)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>150</s> 146 bytes

```python
v=[]
s=0
for c in input():
 v=v[:9]
 if'0'==c:1
 elif 3 in v[-1:]and c in'21':v=v[:-1]
 else:v+=[int(c)]
for x in v[::-1]:s+=s+x%2*(2-x-s)
print s
```

Thanks to Pâris Douady for the points formula, and for saving 4 bytes.

Comment: Did you took my formula for the counting of the point ? Either way nice solution, you beat me and it's much cleaner. also you can save some bytes with by doing `for c in input()` directly

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, <s>267</s> <s>264</s> 249 souls sacrificed

```
r='replace'
f=t=>{t=t[r](/0/g,'');while(/3[12]/.test(t.substring(0,10)))t=t[r](/3[12]/,'');
a=t.length-1;x=(t.substring(0,9)+(a>8?t[a]:'')).split('').reverse().join('');
c='c=0'+x[r](/1/g,'+1')[r](/2/g,';c*=2;c=c')[r](/3/g,'-1');eval(c);return c}
```

Edited version, because the previous one was incorrect for larger inputs. Golfed it a little further by making `string.prototype.replace()` into an array-accessed function call. Explanation:

```
f=t=>{                                  Function declaration, input t
t=t.replace(/0/g,'');                   Remove air
while(/3[12]/.test(t.substring(0,10)))  Look for bombs; not double bombs, and only in the first 10 chars
    t=t.replace(/3[12]/,'');            Detonate bombs. If this makes a new bomb fall into the vase, or
                                        a double bomb is now a single bomb, it'll detonate that bomb too.
x=(t.substring(0,9)+                    Fill the vase, take the first 9 items
    (t.length>9?t[t.length-1]:''))      If we have more than 9 items, then add the last one
    .split('').reverse().join('');      Flip the instruction string.
c='c=0'+x.replace(/1/g,'+1')            Replace each item with the proper instruction to the ACC
         .replace(/2/g,';c*=2;c=c')
         .replace(/3/g,'-1');
eval(c);return c}                       Eval to get the value of ACC and return it.
```

`f('11231');` returns `2`.
[Try it online](https://repl.it/E7ip/1)

Comment: 10100000200310310113030200221013111213110130332101 doesn't return the good result :) You're close though :)

Comment: @Sygmei I know, and I've been debugging the crap out of it, but I can't find out why. Can you [see me in chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49080/the-golfer-adventure-chapter-1-the-vase)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>221 202 181 177</s> 166 <s>souls</s> bytes

```haskell
g(0:r)=r++[0]
g(3:x:r)|0<x,x<3=0:0:g r|1<3=3:g(x:r)
g(x:r)=x:g r
g r=r
v%(x:r)=g(init v++[x])%r
v%[]|v==g v=foldr([id,(+)1,(*)2,(-)1]!!)0v|1<3=g v%[]
(([0..9]>>[0])%)
```

[Try it on ideone](http://ideone.com/CLMFau). Takes items as integer list.

#### Usage:

```haskell
*Prelude> (([0..9]>>[0])%) [1,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,1]
43
```

#### (Edit: Old) Explanation:

```haskell
g [] = []                             -- g simulates gravity in the vase
g ('0':r) = r ++ "0"                  -- the first 0 from the bottom is removed
g ('3':x:r) | elem x "12" = "00"++g r -- if a 1 or 2 is on a bomb, explode 
            | True = '3' : g(x:r)     -- else continue
g (x:r) = x : g r                     -- no air and no bomb, so check next item

c x = [id,(+)1,(*)2,(-)1]!!(read[x])  -- map 0, 1, 2, 3 to their score functions

f v w (x:r) =                         -- v is the current vase state, w the previous one
               init v++[x]            -- replace last vase element with input
             g(init v++[x])           -- simulate one gravity step
           f(g(init v++[x]))v r       -- repeat, w becomes v
f v w[] | v==w =                      -- if the input is empty and vase reached a fixpoint
                 foldr c 0 v          -- then compute score 
        | True = f (g v) v []         -- else simulate another gravity step


vase input = f "0000000000" "" input  -- call f with empty vase, previous vase state and
                                      -- the input as string of numbers
```

Comment: Good job :) ! What are the last three " ?

Comment: @Sygmei it's two strings `f "0000000000" ""`, you just don't need any spaces between them. I added an explanation to the code.

Comment: Nice, easier to understand now :)